# Move cursor to the end of textarea/input in form

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this jQuery code to keep cursor at the end of textarea

```js
jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
      el = this;
    if (!$el.is(":focus")) {
      $el.focus();
    }
    if (el.setSelectionRange) {
      var len = $el.val().length * 2;
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.setSelectionRange(len, len);
      }, 1);
    } else {
      $el.val($el.val());
    }
    this.scrollTop = 999999;
  });
};
(function() {
  var searchInput = $(".search");
  searchInput
    .putCursorAtEnd()
    .on("focus", function() {
      searchInput.putCursorAtEnd()
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
  <p>Name<input class="search" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <p>Email</p> <input class="search" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <p>Message for the author</p><textarea class="search" name="message" rows="6" cols="25" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And it still doesn't do anything with the coursor position. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$(".search")` selects more than one element. Is that intentional?

Comment: It is - As you can see in HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var searchInput = $(".search")
    .on("focus", function(e) {
      var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
      var len = $target.val().length;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $target[0].setSelectionRange(len,len);
      }, 1);
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
  <p>Name<input class="search" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <p>Email</p> <input class="search" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <p>Message for the author</p><textarea class="search" name="message" rows="6" cols="25" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

You can just do :

```
(function() {
  var searchInput = $(".search")
    .on("focus", function(e) {
      var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
      var len = $target.val().length;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $target[0].setSelectionRange(len,len);
      }, 1);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Everything seems to work in snipplets but when I use it on my website it doesn't. Can I send you a link so you'd look into it?

Comment: Yes, for sure :)

Comment: It's just because your script endline.js is called at the top of the DOM.
So at the time of loading the script `.search` does not exist yet.

It's best to call it before end of body </body>.

Or you can use document.ready. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: That's it. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the scrollTop property also only after the focus operation has completed, so with a timeout.

I would suggest to use this trick to set the caret position at the end: clear the input and immediately restore it again. It makes the code a tad smaller and saves you from changing the focus (which may have steal the focus to another input element when a focus operation is already being executed):

```js
jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("").val(value);
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.scrollTop = 999999;
    }.bind(this)); 
  });
};
(function() {
  var searchInput = $(".search");
  searchInput
    .putCursorAtEnd()
    .on("focus", function() {
      searchInput.putCursorAtEnd()
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
  <p>Name<input class="search" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <p>Email</p> <input class="search" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <p>Message for the author</p><textarea class="search" name="message" rows="6" cols="25" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I owe you one! I've forgotten this one.

Comment: Okay, so this snippet indicates everything is okay, I put exactly the same code on my website and it's not working again. jQuery imported from the same link as you provided here and so is the script imported in right way...

Comment: This is because you run the code too soon. Put your script near the end of the `body` tag. Too bad I was already asleep when you commented, or I would replied immediately. ;-)